# GMSMapView Prevents UIScrollView from Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a GMSMapView nested within a UIScrollView. I have turned off scrolling functionality for the GMSMapView

```
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
mapView.settings.scrollGestures = false
mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
```

However, whenever I attempt to scroll the view with the intention that the UIScrollView will scroll, nothing happens. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9):

In swift 3.0

```
mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

detect touch gestures in UIScrollView (touch -> detect which view was touched and enable/disable scrolling of UIScroll view according to that.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
CGPoint viewPoint = [myImage convertPoint:locationPoint fromView:self.view];
if ([mapView pointInside:viewPoint withEvent:event]) {
   disable scrolling
}
}
```